# ActionBarSherlock doesn't show ActionItems when using dialog theme

Tags: android, dialog, themes, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to update my app with the new ActionBar paradigm. I want to keep compatibility backwards though, as my largest user base is still on Gingerbread.

To that end, I am trying to integrate [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) into my app.

My app is designed to use the dialog theme, so when I integrated ABS, I tried to use the corresponding dialog theme as so in my **AndroidManifest.xml**:

`<application android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Dialog" >`

My ActionItems would not show up though, and only appeared as old-school menu items (meaning they were completely inaccessible on my tablet). Looking at the samples in the ABS download, I decided to try changing my app and removing the `.Dialog` qualifier, changing my **AndroidManifest.xml** to:

`<application android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >`

Once I did that, the menu items moved from the menu to the ActionBar, where I expected and want them to be. So it would seem that, with default conditions, ActionItems are not enabled when using the `.Dialog` theme.

Is there any way to enable this behavior, so that the menu items would show in the ActionBar as expected while still using the dialog theme?